# Pythonのファイルをダブルクリックで開いても黒い画面が現れたあと一瞬で消えてしまう

Tags: python

Pythonファイルをオンライン上からダウンロードした後に展開しました。その後、そのファイルを開くと黒い画面（プロンプト）が一瞬現れた後すぐに消えてしまいます。再起動等を試しましたが同じようになってしまいます。

追記
自分は今オライリーのゼロから作るdeeplearningという本を学んでいまして、
https://github.com/oreilly-japan/deep-learning-from-scratch
↑からデータをダウンロードしました。

Comment: 実行した Pythonスクリプトの内容 (オンラインから入手したものならそのURL) と、ファイルをどのように開いたか (Windows でダブルクリック or コマンドプロンプトから実行 etc...) など、もう少し詳しい情報が必要になるかと思います。 / 質問は後からでも [編集] できるので、追記してみてください。

Comment: 展開したら、複数のファイルやフォルダーになったと思います。
「そのファイル」のファイル名は何ですか？そして、どのようにして開いたのですか？

Comment: 「ファイルを開く」とはどのような操作でしょうか？ダブルクリックでしょうか？それともコマンドを入力されているのでしょうか？ダウンロードしたファイルのURLと操作した手順を書けば、回答が得られると思います。Pythonのインストールはできていますか？インストールしたPythonのバージョンはいくつですか？

Comment: 「ファイルを開く」のはダブルクリックで開いていました。

Comment: 質問に書かれているURLのページには、

実行方法

各章のフォルダへ移動して、Pythonコマンドを実行します。

$ cd ch01
$ python man.py

$ cd ../ch05
$ python train_nueralnet.py

と説明されています。（どこにもダブルクリックで開けとは書いていません）
説明通りに操作してみるのが良いのではないですか？

Answer (score 1):

## ファイルを開いて見る方法

プログラミングを始めるのであれば、`テキストエディタ`, `コードエディタ`と呼ばれるツール、もしくは`IDE(Integrated Development Environment)`を入手することを強くおすすめします。

例えば下記です。
https://code.visualstudio.com/

今すぐどうしてもファイルの中身が確認したいというのであれば、GitHub上で直接見ることも可能です。

https://github.com/oreilly-japan/deep-learning-from-scratch/blob/master/ch01/hungry.py

上記は `hungry.py` の中身へのリンクです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

たった1行

```
print("I'm hungry!")
```

と書かれていることがわかります。

## ファイルを実行する方法

ファイルを実行したいのであれば、コメントにも記載されている方がいらっしゃるように

https://github.com/oreilly-japan/deep-learning-from-scratch#%E5%AE%9F%E8%A1%8C%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95

を参考に実行するとよいと考えます。

念のために引用すると下記の部分です。

```
$ cd ch01
$ python man.py

$ cd ../ch05
$ python train_nueralnet.py
```

Answer (score 1):

### 短い回答

どのファイルを開いたかにもよりますが、例えば `ch01\man.py` をダブルクリックで開こうとしたなら
黒い画面が表示されてすぐに消えるのは正しい動作です。

ウィンドウが閉じるのが早過ぎて分かりづらいですが、文字列を表示するプログラムが動いています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

### 細かな補足

1. **どんなプログラムなのかを確認する**
   書籍に掲載されているものやWebで公開されているものなど、自分以外の人が書いたプログラムであるなら、まずどんな動きをするプログラムなのかを事前に確認しましょう。
2. **プログラムの実行方法を確認する**
   Pythonの場合、書き方次第でGUIも扱えますが、基本はテキストベースで利用する事が多いプログラミング言語です。普段Windowsで使用しているような、ダブルクリックしてプログラムを起動するのとは勝手が違います。
   せっかく書籍を参考にしているのなら、記載されている実行方法をよく確認しましょう。

### 参考

以下の様にプログラムを修正すると、ダブルクリックで実行した場合でも数秒間画面を表示したままになり結果が確認できるようになります。

**man.py**

```
# coding: utf-8
import time     ### 追記部分 (その1)
class Man:
    """サンプルクラス"""

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        print("Initilized!")

    def hello(self):
        print("Hello " + self.name + "!")

    def goodbye(self):
        print("Good-bye " + self.name + "!")

m = Man("David")
m.hello()
m.goodbye()
time.sleep(5)   ### 追記部分 (その2)
```

Answer (score 0):

*Windows*であれば開きたいファイルを　**右クリック**して「**プログラムから開く**」をクリックしてから開きたい環境(メモ帳など)を選択すれば開きます。自分の経験でもありましたが簡単です。